# update in MYSQL using php and login

Tags: php, mysql, updating

I am doing an update of values inside a MySQL database using PHP

and here is my code to update

```
$id =  $_REQUEST['uid'];
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$company = $_REQUEST['company'];
$contact = $_REQUEST['contact'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
echo "$id "."$name". "$company" . "$contact" . "$email";
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

else
{
    $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `userName`='$name',`userEmail`='$email',`userCompany`='$company',`userContact`='$contact' WHERE userID = $id";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) 
    {
        mysqli_commit($conn);
        echo "success";
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "error";
    }   
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

it does the update and changes the value in the db.

But when I login using the previous username and password, it still accepts it

code for login

```
$uname= $_REQUEST['loginusername'];
$pword= $_REQUEST['loginpassword'];



// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

} 
else
{

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE userName = '$uname' AND userPassword = '$pword'";
    $return = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($return) >  0)
    {   
        echo 'found';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'not found';
    }
}
$conn->close();
```

thanks in advance

Comment: And question? Error message?

Comment: Wich is your problem? Where do you have errors? edit the question and add error logs...etc

Comment: there is no error. ex the username before update is Oscar and i updated it to Nemo, during login it still accepts the username Oscar whereas there is no Oscar in the database. but i noticed that after 5 mins it doesn't allow oscar anymore

Comment: update password field also.

Comment: **Well as your UPDATE query does not change the password**, it is not really any suprise you can still use the old password.

Comment: @ShamvilU.Gases Edit your question, add the comment as example of what is happening. Thats usefull to see what is going on!!!

Comment: but i'am using AND in my sql query so if the username doesnt exist even the password is the same, it should not get anything

Comment: This might be a MySQL issue. You said that you run update to change `userName`, and that after the update, when you login, the old user name is still accepted. This sound like maybe the transaction is not completed for some reason. Please add schema details for `users` table.

Comment: @Twisty     
here's the img link for the schema of users table https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-9/11182256_1126846400664646_2321891444689889792_n.jpg?oh=3ba9e67e94fce9f9249b44a019296506&oe=55C1DD22&__gda__=1439562523_33378d87c529300989f122ecbea162d5

Comment: it seems your code is very vunerable for SQL injection. Please use prepared statements. http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Please consider using the `PDO` class or a good ORM for PHP

Answer (score 0):

You don't update your Password field in

```
UPDATE `users` SET `userName`='$name',`userEmail`='$email',`userCompany`='$company',`userContact`='$contact' WHERE userID = $id
```

and it isn't a good practice to save clear text passwords. Its better to hash it with an hash algorithm (for example sha256) and salt it.